# Mod Rewrite - HTTPS Redirect Causing 404 Errors

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue where my htaccess file is causing 404 errors with the URLs that are supposed to be rewritten when the HTTPS condition and rules are added. Everything works fine with the rules when the HTTPS condition and rule are removed. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine ON

# All Projects Rule

RewriteRule ^projects/?$ all-projects.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Add Project Rule

RewriteRule ^projects/add/?$ add-new-project.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Assigned Projects Rule

RewriteRule ^projects/assigned/?$ assigned-projects.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Single Project Rule

RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ single-project.php?id=$1&section=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# Single Project Subfolders

RewriteRule ^(projects)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3/?subfolder=$4 [NC,QSA,L]

# All Users Rule

RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ all-users.php?sort=$1&direction=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# Add User Rule

RewriteRule ^users/add-user/?$ add-new-user.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Add Client Rule

RewriteRule ^users/add-client/?$ add-new-client.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Force HTTPS

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</If>
```

Also, here are a few examples of raw URLs and what they become after the rules are applied

1. all-projects.php?id=2&section=documents becomes /projects/2/documents/
2. add-new-user.php becomes /users/add-user/
3. all-users.php?sort=id&direction=asc becomes /users/id/asc

Comment: Make sure `VirtualHost` entry for HTTPS has same `DocumentRoot` as the `HTTP` site.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown efforts/Rules, could you please try following Rules. Please place your htaccess rules file in your root.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

# Force HTTPS
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</If>

# All Projects Rule
RewriteRule ^projects/?$ all-projects.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Add Project Rule
RewriteRule ^projects/add/?$ add-new-project.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Assigned Projects Rule
RewriteRule ^projects/assigned/?$ assigned-projects.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Single Project Rule
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ single-project.php?id=$1&section=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# Single Project Subfolders
RewriteRule ^(projects)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3/?subfolder=$4 [NC,QSA,L]

# All Users Rule
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ all-users.php?sort=$1&direction=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# Add User Rule
RewriteRule ^users/add-user/?$ add-new-user.php [NC,QSA,L]

# Add Client Rule
RewriteRule ^users/add-client/?$ add-new-client.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Same issue I'm afraid, still getting 404 errors

Comment: @DanielKilburn, could you please do let me know path where is your htaccess file and others file present? These rules consider that your htaccess file is residing with php files too.

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the root and yes in the same folder as these PHP files - that's never been an issue before though!

Comment: @DanielKilburn, could you please post samples of urls in here what you are hitting here?

Comment: I've added 3 examples to the original post, thanks

Comment: @DanielKilburn, looks like you have any other rules apart from shown here? Because I can't see redirection rules in your htaccess file but your samples shown redirection, please confirm once.

Comment: I do not have any other rules.